# show certain date in date picker

Tags: javascript, angular, datepicker, pickmeup

I'm using [pickmeup](https://github.com/nazar-pc/PickMeUp) *datePicker* in my Angular project, and it works good and stable but I faced a problem. When I'm trying to set a particular date, picker breaks and/or disappears. I used the method `set_date` from the documentation but I think I'm missing something.

I use the following code

```
showDate(timestamp: number) {
  const timeString = timestamp.toString();
  this.pickerInstance.set_date(new Date(timeString));
}
```

I have a [stackblitz code template here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-epzamd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts).

So the idea is, I want to have a button when I'm pressing on it, it passes timestamp value to `showDate` function and after that *datePicker* shows my date.

I don't want to use jquery here, I believe this could be done without it. But maybe I'm wrong.

Any ideas, comments, help is welcome? thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The [constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Syntax) of `Date` needs a number not a a string.
2. You need to call `this.pickerInstance.update()` after the update

```
public showDate(timestamp: number) {
  this.pickerInstance.set_date(new Date(timestamp));
  this.pickerInstance.update();
}
```